# Access Documents in CosmosDB via the Nuget package when only some have a particular field

Tags: linq, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection in Cosmos DB where some of the documents have a field called "flag" and some don't. So, for example, I might have a document that looks like this...

```
{
    "id": "this"
}
```

and another that looks like this ...

```
{
    "id": "that",
    "flag": "true"
}
```

Using the DocumentDB nuget package I am accessing the collection like this ...

```
const string URL = "https://some-made-up-name.documents.azure.com:443/";
const string ACCESS_KEY = "Some_made_up_Access_key";
const string DATABASE = "database";
const string COLLECTION = "MyCollection";

var _feedOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 1000 };

using (var _client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(URL), ACCESS_KEY))
{
    var list = _client.ReadDocumentFeedAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DATABASE, COLLECTION), _feedOptions).Result;

    list.Select(a => new { a.id, a.flag })
        .ToList()
}
```

If I run this I get the error "Property 'flag' is not in the document.

Is there a way of formulating the query so that I get "null" or "undefined" or something for documents where "flag" isn't defined and the actual value where it is?

Comment: Is your intention to actually retrieve all documents in the collection regardless of their flag value? Or could you just modify this to query for ones that have a value defined for flag?

Comment: @JesseCarter the former. I want to see the value of the flag where it exists and to also see where it doesn't